# image.onError on jquery-mobile while uploading images

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am using PhoneGap to run my JQuery Mobile Hybrid App.

I am following this [tutorial](http://code.hootsuite.com/html5/) in order to upload image from my Device (Samsung Note4, Android 6.0.1) to the `canvas`, I have tried with different types of images but I am always getting the execution result of the `image.onError`.

What could be the reason of getting the `image.onError` execution?

Here is the code from the tutorial:

```
function processFile(dataURL, fileType) {
    var maxWidth = 800;
    var maxHeight = 800;

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = dataURL;

    image.onload = function () {
        var width = image.width;
        var height = image.height;
        var shouldResize = (width > maxWidth) || (height > maxHeight);

        if (!shouldResize) {
            sendFile(dataURL);
            return;
        }

        var newWidth;
        var newHeight;

        if (width > height) {
            newHeight = height * (maxWidth / width);
            newWidth = maxWidth;
        } else {
            newWidth = width * (maxHeight / height);
            newHeight = maxHeight;
        }

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        canvas.width = newWidth;
        canvas.height = newHeight;

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(fileType);

        sendFile(dataURL);
    };

    image.onerror = function () {
        alert('There was an error processing your file!');
    };
}
```